# PHP SimpleXML get date range

Tags: php, xml, date-range

I have problems to get a date range with php simpleXML.

So my XML structure looks like this:

```
    <events>
    <event_data>
        <id>1</id>
        <startdate realdate="2013-08-06">1375740000</startdate>
        <enddate realdate="2013-08-13">1376344800</enddate>
    </event_data>

    <event_data>
        <id>2</id>
        <startdate realdate="2013-08-10">1376085600</startdate>
        <enddate realdate="2013-08-17">1376690400</enddate>
    <event_data>

    <event_data>
        <id>3</id>
        <startdate realdate="2013-08-17">1376690400</startdate>
        <enddate realdate="2013-08-24">1377295200</enddate>
    </event_data>

    <event_data>
        <id>4</id>
        <startdate realdate="2013-08-24">1377295200</startdate>
        <enddate realdate="2013-09-07">1378504800</enddate>
    <event_data>

    <event_data>
        <id>5</id>
        <startdate realdate="2013-08-25">1377381600</startdate>
        <enddate realdate="2013-09-08">1378591200</enddate>
    </event_data>

    <event_data>
        <id>6</id>
        <startdate realdate="2013-09-15">1379196000</startdate>
        <enddate realdate="2013-09-23">1379887200</enddate>
    <event_data>

    <event_data>
        <id>7</id>
        <startdate realdate="2013-10-26">1382738400</startdate>
            <enddate realdate="2013-11-02">1383346800</enddate>
    </event_data>

    <event_data>
        <id>8</id>
        <startdate realdate="2013-11-10">1384038000</startdate>
        <enddate realdate="2013-11-15">1384470000</enddate>
    <event_data>

    <event_data>
        <id>9</id>
        <startdate realdate="2014-01-11">1389394800</startdate>
        <enddate realdate="2014-01-18">1389999600</enddate>
    </event_data>

    <event_data>
        <id>10</id>
        <startdate realdate="2014-01-19">1390086000</startdate>
        <enddate realdate="2014-01-24">1390518000</enddate>
    <event_data>
</events>
```

and much more entries like that with different start and end dates.

my php script looks like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div id="slider-range"></div>
    <input type="text" name="startdate" style="margin:40px 0 0">
    <input type="text" name="enddate" style="margin:40px 0 0">

    <input type="submit" name="submitClub" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php

?>

<div id="eventList">
<?php 

    $sxe = simplexml_load_file('events.xml');  

    if($sxe) {  
        if(isset($_POST['submitClub'])) {

            $varStart = $_POST['startdate'];
            $varEnd = $_POST['enddate'];

            if($varStart) {
                foreach($sxe->xpath('//event_data') as $item) {
                    $row = simplexml_load_string($item->asXML()); 

                $start = strtotime($varStart);
                $end = strtotime($varEnd);

                $v = $row->xpath('//startdate[. ="' . $start . '"]'); 
                $z = $row->xpath('//enddate[. ="' . $end . '"]');

                while($v <= $z){
?>
                    <div class="item <?php echo $item->categoryid ?> clearfix">
                        <div class="left">
                            <div class="header_data">
                                <h2><?php echo $item->name ?></h2>
                                <div class="date"><?php 
                                    $startdate = $item->startdate->attributes()->realdate;
                                        $enddate = $item->enddate->attributes()->realdate;
                                        echo date("d.m.Y", strtotime($startdate)) . ' - ' . date("d.m.Y", strtotime($enddate)); 
                                    ?></div>
                                    <div class="club"><?php echo $item->club ?></div>
                                    <div class="theme"><?php echo $item->theme ?></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
<?php                   $start = $start + 86400;
                        $v = $row->xpath('//startdate[. ="' . $start . '"]');
                    }
                }
            } else {
                echo 'Keine Events';
            }
        }       
    } else {
        echo '<p>Die Datei konnte nicht geöffnet werden</p>';
    } 
?>
</div>
```

So if a user choose in the slider-range the startdate as August 10, 2013 and as an enddate September 12, 2013 the follwing events should be displayed:

```
<events>
<event_data>
    <id>1</id>
    <startdate realdate="2013-08-06">1375740000</startdate>
    <enddate realdate="2013-08-13">1376344800</enddate>
</event_data>

<event_data>
    <id>2</id>
    <startdate realdate="2013-08-10">1376085600</startdate>
    <enddate realdate="2013-08-17">1376690400</enddate>
<event_data>

<event_data>
    <id>3</id>
    <startdate realdate="2013-08-17">1376690400</startdate>
    <enddate realdate="2013-08-24">1377295200</enddate>
</event_data>

<event_data>
    <id>4</id>
    <startdate realdate="2013-08-24">1377295200</startdate>
    <enddate realdate="2013-09-07">1378504800</enddate>
<event_data>

<event_data>
    <id>5</id>
    <startdate realdate="2013-08-25">1377381600</startdate>
    <enddate realdate="2013-09-08">1378591200</enddate>
</event_data>
```

The start and enddate is dynamic and not static, so the user can choose also other start and end dates.

So if a user choose a date range between December 24, 2013 and July 15, 2014 these evenets should be displayed:

```
<event_data>
    <id>9</id>
    <startdate realdate="2014-01-11">1389394800</startdate>
    <enddate realdate="2014-01-18">1389999600</enddate>
</event_data>

<event_data>
    <id>10</id>
    <startdate realdate="2014-01-19">1390086000</startdate>
    <enddate realdate="2014-01-24">1390518000</enddate>
<event_data>
```

I hope this clarifys what I need.

Maybe someone can help or give me a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit tricky to get the XPath right but this should do it:

```
$events = simplexml_load_file('events.xml');

$xpath = sprintf(
    '/events/event_data[
        (%1$d >= startdate and %2$d <= enddate)
        or
        (%1$d <= enddate and %2$d >= startdate)
    ]',
    strtotime('December 24, 2013'),
    strtotime('July 15, 2014')
);

var_dump($events->xpath($xpath));
```

This selects an `<event_data>` element when *(the user supplied startdate is after or on the event startdate **and** the user supplied enddate is before or on the event enddate)* **or** *(the user supplied enddate is before or on the end date **and** the startdate is on or after the event startdate)*.

**Demos:** http://eval.in/42811 and http://eval.in/42812

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your help, I really appreciate your effort to help me :)

Comment: I have one more question. If I want to display all events that start during the given date range, what do I have to do then?
I have already tried to make it work with a while loop but that was not successful.

Comment: @kathi just query for any event_data where link/startdate is between the user supplied start and end date. If that doesn't work for you, consider creating a new question for it.